# useEffect and fetch make local state undefined

Tags: reactjs

`books` state is initialized to `[]`, yet after using `useEffect` I get the `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')` error.

```
    const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:3001/books")
            .then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error("Request failed");
                }
                response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                setBooks(data);
            })
            .catch((error) => setError(error));
    }, []);

    if (error !== null) {
        return <div>An error has occurred: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (books.length === 0) {
        return <div>No books found</div>;
    }
```

If I completely remove the `useEffect` block then it behaves as expected.

Comment: Your first `.then` needs a `return`. Ie, `return response.json()`